# Arduino RPM code with Quadrature Encoder 600ppr

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno, encoder

I'm attempting to setup my arduino uno in such a way as that it provides me with the RPM being measured on my encoder. So far I have been able to figure out how to accurately measure the RPM for the first value, however I am struggling to reset the value at the end of the loop, so instead of giving me the actual revolutions its just incrementing with the previous data. Here is my code for a better understanding of what I mean ...

```
// Red - 5V
// Black - GND

const int encoder_a = 2; // Green - pin 2 - Digital
const int encoder_b = 3; // White - pin 3 - Digital
long encoder = 0;
long encoderO=0;


void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(encoder_a, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(encoder_b, INPUT_PULLUP);

    attachInterrupt(0, encoderPinChangeA, CHANGE);
    attachInterrupt(1, encoderPinChangeB, CHANGE);
}

void loop() {
    Serial.println(encoder/2400.00*60);
    delay(1000);
}

void encoderPinChangeA() {
    encoder += digitalRead(encoder_a) == digitalRead(encoder_b) ? -1 : 1;
}

void encoderPinChangeB() {
    encoder += digitalRead(encoder_a) != digitalRead(encoder_b) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Good answer by Wessels. Some small bugs in the code provided, complete working and tested code:

```
const int encoder_a = 3; // Pin 3
const int encoder_b = 5; // Pin 5
long encoder_pulse_counter = 0;
long direction = 1;

void encoderPinChangeA()
{
    encoder_pulse_counter += 1;
    direction = digitalRead(encoder_a) == digitalRead(encoder_b) ? -1 : 1;
}

void encoderPinChangeB()
{
    encoder_pulse_counter += 1;
    direction = digitalRead(encoder_a) != digitalRead(encoder_b) ? -1 : 1;
}

void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(encoder_a, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(encoder_b, INPUT_PULLUP);
    attachInterrupt(0, encoderPinChangeA, CHANGE);
    attachInterrupt(1, encoderPinChangeB, CHANGE);
}

void loop()
{
    long speed = encoder_pulse_counter/1024.00*60; // For encoder plate with 1024 Pulses per Revolution
    Serial.print("RPM: ");
    Serial.println(direction*speed);
    encoder_pulse_counter = 0; // Clear variable just before counting again 
    delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to restructure the code a little. This is mainly to separate the speed and direction, as they don't rely on each other. For example:

```
long encoder_pulse_counter = 0;
long direction = 1


void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(encoder_a, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(encoder_b, INPUT_PULLUP);

    attachInterrupt(0, encoderPinChangeA, CHANGE);
    attachInterrupt(1, encoderPinChangeB, CHANGE);
}

void loop(){
    long speed = encoder_pulse_counter/2400.00*60; // Not sure, encoder not specified
    Serial.println(direction*speed);
    encoder_pulse_counter = 0; // Clear variable just before counting again 
    delay(1000);
}


void encoderPinChangeA(){
    encoder_pulse_counter += 1;
    direction = digitalRead(encoder_a) == digitalRead(encoder_b) ? -1 : 1;
}

void encoderPinChangeB(){
    encoder_pulse_counter += 1;
    direction = digitalRead(encoder_a) != digitalRead(encoder_b) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

I didn't test this code, so there might be small bugs. But I think separating the calculations will be much easier. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
volatile long encoder_pulse_counter = 0;
volatile long direction = 1


void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(encoder_a, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(encoder_b, INPUT_PULLUP);

    attachInterrupt(0, encoderPinChangeA, CHANGE);
    attachInterrupt(1, encoderPinChangeB, CHANGE);
}

void loop(){
    long speed = encoder_pulse_counter/2400.00*60; // Not sure, encoder not specified
    Serial.println(direction*speed);
    encoder_pulse_counter = 0; // Clear variable just before counting again 
    delay(1000);
}


void encoderPinChangeA(){
    encoder_pulse_counter += 1;
    direction = digitalRead(encoder_a) == digitalRead(encoder_b) ? -1 : 1;
}

void encoderPinChangeB(){
    encoder_pulse_counter += 1;
    direction = digitalRead(encoder_a) != digitalRead(encoder_b) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

agree it looks good just add volatile to any variable used in a ISR..