# Setting up Pulse per revolution value for RPM calculation with incremental encoder

Tags: arduino, encoder

This question is based on the following thread: [Arduino RPM code with Quadrature Encoder 600ppr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51297371/arduino-rpm-code-with-quadrature-encoder-600ppr?newreg=d60b345bf3b14b30af718b019c5605e4)

Code:

```
const int encoder_a = 3; // Pin 3
const int encoder_b = 5; // Pin 5
long encoder_pulse_counter = 0;
long direction = 1;

void encoderPinChangeA()
{
    encoder_pulse_counter += 1;
    direction = digitalRead(encoder_a) == digitalRead(encoder_b) ? -1 : 1;
}

void encoderPinChangeB()
{
    encoder_pulse_counter += 1;
    direction = digitalRead(encoder_a) != digitalRead(encoder_b) ? -1 : 1;
}

void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(encoder_a, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(encoder_b, INPUT_PULLUP);
    attachInterrupt(0, encoderPinChangeA, CHANGE);
    attachInterrupt(1, encoderPinChangeB, CHANGE);
}

void loop()
{
    long speed = encoder_pulse_counter/**1024**.00*60; // For encoder plate with 1024 Pulses per Revolution
    Serial.print("RPM: ");
    Serial.println(direction*speed);
    encoder_pulse_counter = 0; // Clear variable just before counting again 
    delay(1000);
}
```

I used this code and it works, but I have a hard time figuring out how to set this up for my own encoder (which is rated as 400pulses per minute, ref LPD3806-400BM-G5-24C).

I tried the code using 400 (my encoder is 400ppr) as value to define the value of the "speed" variable

```
long speed = encoder_pulse_counter/**1024.00"*60;
```

I tested with a power drill that's supposed to give 500rpm (no load, 1st gear), but with the 400 value, I get a printed RPM of about 7800RPM... Any idea about the value I should put in there?

Comment: this does not even compile. ` long speed = encoder_pulse_counter/**1024**.00*60;` causes an error for an unterminated comment. so does `long speed = encoder_pulse_counter/**1024.00"*60;`    did you try to make this number bold or what is this abomination? you cannot format text inside a code block.

Comment: also your statement about the rated pulses per minute is wrong. 400 is the pulses per revolution. not pulses per minute. you can go thousands of revolutions per minute with an encoder like this. further you should post the code you actually executed. not some other code explaining that you used some numbers. how do we know you used those numbers properly? if you replace 1024 with 400 this should work.

Comment: Hi,
I indeed tried to highlight the value in bold... Which I realize was not a good idea... Regarding the "Pulse per minute", it's a typing mistake. I know (and wrote many times) that these are Pulses Per Revolution...